# Do I really need to use ajax for non-page-loading website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, page-load-time

getting straight to the point, I am designing an online Test Series (/objective exams) website with PHP. The thing I want to tell you here that, I want to load whole test series at once, so that after starting the Test, user don't have to wait up for the next or previous questions. (I am trying to do that with ajax). I am also maintaining the 'question map' for tracking and letting the user know about the attempted questions as in attached demo GUI picture.

[image: DEMO GUI FOR TEST SERIES WEBSITE]

Now I have 2 questions..
1) Is it really possible? To maintain question map if the system is loading next pages without calling to the database (As ajax do)
2) How. And do I really need to use ajax template for my purpose.

NOTE: All I want is to load newer questions with no/minimum page load but with maintaining proper DB calls. Any suggestions are appreciated. Or any new way to attain this??

Comment: Sure, you can include all relevant data on the initial page load.  You'd just use JavaScript to maintain the state of the UI much as you do now, except that it has the data it needs already instead of fetching it via AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, but as you can see in the picture, that I am turning backgrounds into the orange for the questions I have attempted. So, to let the system know about changes, DB must get the calls about answer submission for the question.. So, just maintaining the UI/front end can't attain this.. I guess

Comment: Well, if you need to interact with the server, then you need to send requests to the server and receive responses.  If you don't need to interact with the server, then you don't.  It's not really clear what you're asking in this case...

Comment: more precisely, i need.. "No/minimum Page Load + Database Calls (maintained at server)"

Comment: the database calls have to be initiated by the client, but otherwise i don't see anything that would stop you from doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: No, just getting it clear that, to make server calls, i really need the 'page loads'..  right? But as this can waste the time of students who are giving the test. So, how to make this happen..?  [no/minimum page load + server calls]

Comment: @Low-Pointer: That's not really "more precise." You might be able to optimize your data and/or logic, but we can't really know with the current information. At the very least, any data that's needed client-side will need to be present client-side. So either that data is included as part of the initial page load or it's fetched from the server at a later time. Any data that needs to be persisted on the server would need to be sent to the server. If you have any *specific* questions about optimizing some data/code then we may be able to help with that, but not from just screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you seem a little confused about AJAX. AJAX is the primary method for client side calls. As opposed to using a server side language, like PHP or C# w/ ASP.NET, you can use Javascript to make database calls after the page loads.

What you seem to be asking is if you can load a large amount of data on page load and then organize it with Javascript. This is entirely possible. However, it requires large database calls, as well as more memory(RAM) to store the data, and increased time to load the data. The RAM factor should be relatively small, and ajax would only provide micro-optimizations to that, as long as your data is relatively efficiently stored and not incredibly massive. You should note that database calls can quickly get expensive. If you choose to load all data on page load, will the users consume all of that data? If not, then you are wasting their computer's memory, the time they take to load the page, their bandwidth, as well as making unnecessarily large calls to your own database.

So your main concerns, IMO, should be page load time and reducing the number of unnecessary calls to the database. Will the amount of data being sent negatively impact load times? Are you sending hundreds of records? Will the users consume all of the data if you send it all at once (many websites have 30-50% bounce rates, meaning 30-50% of users leave immediately)? Would it be better to chunk the data and not send half of it until they're ready for the second half?

It sounds like you're only calling the data for a small quiz, which is relatively insignificant. E.g. if your loading 20 questions, and 4 answers, you should just use server side calls. On the other hand, if it's hundreds of questions, with lots of extraneous data, then perhaps you should use AJAX.